# how to set foreignkey value in child serializer in django rest framework when the parent record exists

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

I have two models first as parent model "Country", that filled before the second one as child model "City". as the following

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    icon = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    country = models.ForeignKey(to=Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My serializers.py for my need as following :

```
class CountrySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:

        model = Country
        fields = '__all__'

class CitySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Country.objects.all())

    class Meta:

        model = City
        fields = ('name', 'country')
```

view.py

```
class CountryAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, AllowAnonymous]


class CityAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = City.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CitySerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, AllowAnonymous]

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = CitySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

now when i run get api it run and gives me a result fine . But when im trying to create a new city and set "country":"id" in json i got this error

Cannot assign "2": "City.country" must be a "Country" instance.

So if i was  not clear ,, what i need is exactly set foreign key to city when i create city ,, not create city and country,,

please any one had a solution help, because i tried many ways and read the django rest framework docs about this point but i didn't got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the [**`raise_exception`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#using-is_validraise_exceptiontrue) should be a boolean value (either **`True`** or **`False`**)

You could avoid this error by using inheriting the view class from [ListCreateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview)

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView
```

class CityAPIView(**ListCreateAPIView**):
    queryset = City.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CitySerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, AllowAnonymous]
You don't want to use the **`post()`** method if you're using `ListCreateAPIView`, because DRF will take care of that part well.

**Suggestion**
Since you're dealing with ***CRUD*** functionalities of the model, you can use the DRF's [ModelViewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) class

Comment: can you please see this question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850354/multipart-parser-in-django-rest-framework

many thanks @JPG

Answer (score 1):

you are not using the validated data to create a new city, just change this line:

```
        serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
```

to this:

```
        serializer.save()
```

when you perform `serializer.save()`, the serializer will use its validated data.

also, DRF has a generic view([ListCreateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview)) that covers your use-case.